# VS 2022 (17.4.3) отображает проекты некорректно

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я не новичок, но проблема серьезная, буквально неделю назад обновил vs 2022, до этого версия была вроде с августа или мая. И дело в том, что сама студия, не коректно открывает sln и csproj файлы, когда пытаюсь открыть проект, выдавая ошибку, что "один или несколько проектов в решении не были правильно загружены", и отрывает файлы как будто я решил их просто открыть без самого проекта.
Так-же, при попытке создать проект, он его как-бы создает, но открывает все файлы будто так-же я просто их через проводник клацнул по .cs, и так-же обозреватель решений пуст.
Что насчет кнопки Run, то она полностью изменена на "присоединится к процессу".

Хочу сказать, если вы посоветуете переустановить, попытаться через vs installer исправить версию, то я пробовал!

Конечно я не профессионал, но исправление данной фигни в интернете я не смог найти.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если новый проект создать? Установщик запускали? Разработка .NET приложений там отмечена? Самое простое - снести и переустановить с сайта. Возможно что-то поломалось при обновлении.

Comment: @aepot, проект новый создавал, на 1ом скрине он как раз и есть. vs удалял вчера и ни раз. разработка .net приложений отмечена.

Comment: Что в окне "Вывод" написано? Вам ведь в ошибке сказали посмотреть туда первым делом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "PascalsTriangle.csproj : error  : Не удается открыть файл проекта. Не удается найти пакет SDK для .NET. Убедитесь, что пакет установлен, PATH настроен для правильной архитектуры и версия, указанная в файле global.json (если он имеется), соответствует установленной."

Comment: @EvgeniyZ но так-же при этом если открывать другие проекты, то такого предупреждения может и не быть, но среда будет выглядеть как на 1 скриншоте, а именно как будто открыли просто cs файл

Comment: Вам надо в текстовом редакторе открыть файлы проектов и подредактировать, чтобы версии компонентов соответствовали установленным. Вообще обычно это происходит автоматически при миграции старых проектов.

Comment: @user7860670 даже создавая новые проекты - такая проблема, о чем так-же писалось

Comment: Тогда откройте проекты и посмотрите, какая там версия прописана, и установлена ли она.

Comment: _Не удается найти пакет SDK для .NET._ - значит не установлен SDK, не все нужные галочки отмечены в установщике.

Comment: @user7860670 да, там указан 6ой net, и он установлен.

Comment: @aepot https://sun9-55.userapi.com/impg/1Ta7o-qTzaK9cckwch5Ds2G-vXYOW8rhByyyEQ/eN5Or22xETo.jpg?size=1280x720&quality=96&sign=98013bbbe79e31e22abc4ab907c7f51c&type=album https://sun9-81.userapi.com/impg/mjjcnJ9dO40n8dg-quMMPw7D8wz09BK7gVOspg/D4a__KaVtIA.jpg?size=1280x720&quality=96&sign=32974ec3da962567d9207d9f1fbbe898&type=album

Comment: Если вам пишет ошибку, что нет SDK, значит его нет. Не верьте интерфейсу, верьте ошибкам (и то не всегда). Вот откройте консоль, напишите там `dotnet --list-sdks`, будет там тот SDK, что указан в `.csproj` файле? Да и выполнится вообще команда? Почитайте [это](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions), а также [это](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/windows). Просто так вам писать об отсутсвие SDK не будут.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за наводку, переустановил sdk, но увы проблема та-же, и кстати в папке dotnet, sdk и так стояла

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос, что вам дает команда, которую я дал выше.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ попросту ничего. а если в чаровском то \n )

Comment: Ну вот и ваша проблема, а должно выдать список всех установленных SDK ([пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFLkK.png)). Другими словами, у вас нет SDK, от этого и все проблемы. Разбирайтесь почему установщик SDK не ставит вам все как нужно, читайте выше по ссылкам как ставить SDK, ну и так далее.